# Why does Mage.exe not generate a compatibleFrameworks attribute?

Tags: .net-4.0, clickonce, mage

We are using [Mage.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acz3y3te.aspx) to generate our application's manifests as part of our build process. Upon upgrading to [.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework) 4 we now find it generates an invalid manifest.

The reason is there isn't a compatibleFrameworks attribute being set in the application manifest which we generate every build.

Is there a way we can make Mage.exe add this element or should we only ever update existing manifests?

Comment: Did you ever get this fixed?!?!?!?!?!?!

Comment: I'm also needing a fix for this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add this to your GenerateDeploymentManifest MSBuild task

```
   TargetFrameworkMoniker=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"
```

and that should fix it

Comment: error MSB4064: The "TargetFrameworkMoniker" parameter is not supported by the "GenerateDeploymentManifest" task. Verify the parameter exists on the task, and it is a settable public instance property.

Comment: If you get error 4064 you need to change <Project ToolsVersion="4.0".../> make sure the ToolsVersion is update to 4.0 from 3.5

Answer (score 7):

There is a separate copy of `mage.exe` built for .NET 4.0. Try using this copy from `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools` (or `...\v7.1\Bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools` depending on which SDK version you have installed).

I was actually having this same problem and using the `mage.exe` from `NETFX 4.0 Tools` fixed it for me.

Comment: Just to confirm that there is indeed a .Net 4 specific mage.exe (version 4.0.30319.1). The previous version was 3.5.30729.1 and using that version for a .Net 4 application results in the reported error for me.

Comment: If you've tried "all the versions" of mage / mageUI and had no success (as I did) then you might want to look at calling the MSBuild task from code as is mentioned [in this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11141655/updating-deployment-manifest-for-a-clickonce-application-programmatically-result)