# MageUI.exe is not including a compatibleFrameworks element

Tags: .net-4.0, clickonce

I've got a ClickOnce .NET 4 application deployed by Visual Studio 2010, via a [UNC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_%28computing%29#Uniform_Naming_Convention) path. I open the *.application* file, change the startup location to use the HTTP address, sign, and close. The application then gives this error:

> Application manifest does not accept specification of <compatibleFrameworks>.

How do I get [MageUI.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xhctdw55.aspx) to include this needed element when I sign?

This is similar to Stack Overflow question *[Why does Mage.exe not generate a compatibleFrameworks attribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2654320)*.

I've tried opening MageUI from the location suggested, to no avail, and I'd really rather not have to use [MSBuild](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MSBuild). This is a simple application, and I'd much prefer Visual Studio's simple built-in deployment.

Also, in case anyone's wondering, I can't deploy via HTTP through Visual Studio, because that requires FrontPage extensions to be installed, among other reasons.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using the MageUI.exe version from the .NET 4 folder, which is in:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools
```

By the way, you can set the publishing file location to the UNC share path and the installation URL to your HTTP address and THEN publish. It will put the files on the share, but the installation URL will be set. If that's all you're changing, that would be easier all the way around.

Also, just FYI, you can publish with FTP (publishing a file location is something like `ftp://myserver/myfolder/`) if you don't want (or can't) to install the [FPSE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FrontPage_Server_Extensions).

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I'm honestly now having trouble reproducing the original problem consistently, so I'm going to just run with your other idea, and deploy with the installation folder http, and the publish location UNC.  We can have our server admin install Visual studio to do the same thing with prod, and hopefully that wil solve this problem.