# MageUI.exe removes compatibleFrameworks element

Tags: .net-4.0, clickonce

We use MageUI.exe to manually create different versions of our ClickOnce deployment for development, test and production. We change the *Publisher* in order to have the program icon appear in a separate folder of the Start Menu. We use the MageUI.exe version in the [Microsoft Windows SDK for Windows 7 and .NET Framework 4](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=6b6c21d2-2006-4afa-9702-529fa782d63b) (AKA Microsoft [Windows SDK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Windows_SDK) 7.1). This version shows 4.0.30319.1 as its version number.

Our *.application*-files contain a `<compatibleFrameworks>` element, which is needed for .NET 4.0 deployments.

Normally, when we modify the *.application* file and save it, the `<compatibleFrameworks>` element remains untouched. So far so good.

But... when we save the file twice, the `<compatibleFrameworks>` element is suddenly removed from the *.application*-file!

This seems like a very strange bug to me. Why would MageUI.exe do something else when you save twice?!

#### Update

Assuming this is a bug, [I've also reported it to Microsoft](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/671776/mageui-exe-removes-compatibleframeworks-element-from-application-file).

#### Update 2

Unfortunately, Microsoft won't fix it.

(This question is similar to *[MageUI.exe is not including a compatibleFrameworks element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3471194/mageui-not-including-compatibleframeworks-element)* but not exactly.)

Answer (score 0):

Try using the version of mageui that is specifically provided for the .NET 4 Framework.

It is here:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools
or here:
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools

Comment: That is the same version, and even if it weren't, the 7.1 SDK version would be newer than the 7.0 SDK version.

Comment: You're right. I've reproduced this. I voted up your bug (even though it's closed), and send it to the ClickOnce guy at Microsoft to see if they really aren't ever going to fix it. If I get back any response that says they ARE going to fix it, I'll report back here. In the meantime, if you close mageUI and re-open it before making the second change, that does work. You just can't save it more than once.

Comment: Not saving is the obvious workaround here. Unfortunately, I am not the one having to save the manifest. I've written instructions for our service desk guys so they can modify the ClickOnce deployement for our Test and Production environments. Now I have to try and make sure they don't save it twice.

Comment: This is so crazy that MS won't fix it. How are you guys getting around this once the element is removed? Do you manually add it back in?

Comment: @Kilhoffer: that's what we do.