# Updating deployment manifest for a ClickOnce application programmatically results in missing <compatibleFrameworks> element, required in 4.0

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, installation, clickonce

I'm working on automating the installer for a .NET 4.0 ClickOnce WPF application, which needs a few items to be set in the *app.config* file. I've gone through the thorny process of finding specific steps I must follow using [Mage.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acz3y3te.aspx) (that is, update and re-sign application and deployment manifests) and now am trying to automate it for installation.

I opted to use *.deploy* extension to minimize issues with [IIS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Information_Services)/Internet Explorer security mechanisms, so essentially the algorithm is as follows (based on *[Signing and re-signing manifests in ClickOnce (Saurabh Bhatia)](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsto/archive/2009/04/29/signing-and-re-signing-manifests-in-clickonce.aspx)* and *[Update Configuration of a ClickOnce WPF Application Using Mage or MageUI](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/tutorials/xaml/a8788ed5-c1b5-41d5-b49c-ea4760c3b820/update-configuration-of-a-clickonce-wpf-application-using-mage-or-mageui.aspx)*, as primary sources among others):

1. Go to the `\Application Files\App_%HighestVersion%\` folder
2. Remove *.deploy* extension for files that have it
3. Run  `mage -u %app%.exe.manifest -cf cert.pfx`
4. Restore *.deploy* extension
5. Run  `mage -u %app%.application -appm %app%.exe.manifest -cf cert.pfx`
6. Copy `%app%.application` 2 levels up (to `..\..` - deployment root)

That works perfectly if done manually. I can run a *.cmd* file, customized for environment specifics (paths, etc.), but then I'd need to include `mage.exe` in the deployment, and whether Microsoft allows us to do that is an open question for me. Thus, I'm trying to perform similar actions in the `Installer` class:

```
X509Certificate2 ct = new X509Certificate2(sPathCert);

//  .. Remove .deploy extension (for files in the sPathApp folder).

sPathMft = Directory.GetFiles(sPathApp, "*.exe.manifest")[0];
ApplicationManifest am = ManifestReader.ReadManifest( "ApplicationManifest", sPathMft, false ) as ApplicationManifest;
if (am == null)
    throw new ArgumentNullException("AppManifest");
am.ResolveFiles();
am.UpdateFileInfo( );
ManifestWriter.WriteManifest(am, sPathMft);
SecurityUtilities.SignFile(ct, null, sPathMft);

//    .. Restore .deploy extensions to files touched above.

sPathMft = Directory.GetFiles(sPathApp, "*.application")[0];
DeployManifest dm = ManifestReader.ReadManifest("DeployManifest", sPathMft, false) as DeployManifest;
if (dm == null)
    throw new ArgumentNullException( "DplManifest" );
dm.ResolveFiles();
dm.UpdateFileInfo();
ManifestWriter.WriteManifest(dm, sPathMft);
SecurityUtilities.SignFile(ct, null, sPathMft);

File.Copy(sPathMft, sPathBin + "\\" + dm.AssemblyIdentity.Name, true);
```

**Now, here's the kicker**. Everything works perfectly with exception of step 5. When the application is downloaded to the user's machine there's an issue with the deployment manifest:

- Deployment manifest is not semantically valid.
- Deployment manifest is missing <compatibleFrameworks>.

Indeed, this section is no longer present (*however, it was in the original %app%.application*!). A similar outcome is described in *[ClickOnce - .NET 4.0 errors: "Deployment manifest is not semantically valid" and "Deployment manifest is missing <compatibleFrameworks>"](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/msiclickonce/archive/2010/08/03/clickonce-net-4-0-errors-quot-deployment-manifest-is-not-semantically-valid-quot-and-quot-deployment-manifest-is-missing-lt-compatibleframeworks-gt-quot.aspx)*, but is a result of a different process (msbuild).  This section is new (and required) for 4.0 manifests, so my only guess is that somehow when ManifestWriter persists changes to disk it does it in a 3.5 fashion?  I triple checked that a correct library is used (C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.0\Microsoft.Build.Tasks.v4.0.dll).  **What gives?**

In lieu of an answer so far I tried to add the missing section manually:

```
dm.CompatibleFrameworks.Clear(); // Unnecessary as dm.CompatibleFrameworks.Count == 0 indeed!
CompatibleFramework cf = new CompatibleFramework();
cf.Version= "4.0";
cf.SupportedRuntime = "4.0.30319";
cf.Profile= "Client";
dm.CompatibleFrameworks.Add(cf);
cf = new CompatibleFramework();
cf.Version = "4.0";
cf.SupportedRuntime = "4.0.30319";
cf.Profile = "Full";
dm.CompatibleFrameworks.Add(cf);
```

But that has no effect, no matter where I place this code, before *dm.ResolveFiles( )*, *dm.UpdateFileInfo( )* or *ManifestWriter.WriteManifest(..)*!

My result is similar to Stack Overflow questions *[MageUI.exe removes compatibleFrameworks element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6186282/)* or *[Why does Mage.exe not generate a compatibleFrameworks attribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2654320/)* or *[MageUI.exe is not including a compatibleFrameworks element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3471194/)*, but I'm not using  `mageui`, `mage` or even `msbuild` at all!

What's going on?

Comment: As a workaround, have you tried to directly manipulate the manifest XML instead of using the APIs? It worked for us in the past - you get full control over the contents, do whatever you want, and then re-sign the file once you're done.

Comment: Astrogator - is there any chance that you could share you scripts? I am about to start a very similar process. Thanks!

Comment: Hi @ErickT!  Well, the algorithm is pretty much laid out here.  This code is executed by msiexec.exe via a Custom Action, which i specify in the Visual Studio 2010 Setup project - there are no 'scripts' per se.  Let me know, if that is not clear enough, and i'll try to expose more.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Figured it out myself.  The culprit is *ManifestReader.ReadManifest( "DeployManifest", sPathMft, **true** )*.

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms125928) says, [preserveStream argument] *"specifies whether to preserve the input stream in the InputStream property of the resulting manifest object. Used by ManifestWriter to reconstitute input which is not represented in the object representation."*

Wording aside, setting **true** is not enough by itself:  `dm.CompatibleFrameworks.Count` will still be 0, but now the addition of `CompatibleFramework` items will have an effect!

For someone else in the same boat, I do that before `dm.ResolveFiles( )`:

```
if(  dm.CompatibleFrameworks.Count <= 0  )
{
    CompatibleFramework cf= new CompatibleFramework( );
    cf.Profile= "Client";       cf.Version= "4.0";      cf.SupportedRuntime=    "4.0.30319";
    dm.CompatibleFrameworks.Add( cf );              //  cf= new CompatibleFramework( );
    cf.Profile= "Full";     //  cf.Version= "4.0";      cf.SupportedRuntime=    "4.0.30319";
    dm.CompatibleFrameworks.Add( cf );              /// no need for separate object
}
```

@davidair, thanks for your suggestion!   Agreed, though I prefer to work with API objects (vs. XML).
Another alternative is to call `mage` (directly or from a .cmd file), as it seems that we [are allowed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff699301.aspx) to redistribute it.

---

I also added the following portion, which doesn't have an impact on the question itself, but may be quite important for anyone following the same path (*/client* is the deployment root, and can be customized):

```
dm.DeploymentUrl=   string.Format( "http://{0}/{1}/client/{1}.application",
                        Dns.GetHostName( ), Context.Parameters[ scTokVirtDir ] );
dm.UpdateMode=      UpdateMode.Background;
dm.UpdateUnit=      UpdateUnit.Weeks;
dm.UpdateInterval=  1;
dm.UpdateEnabled=   true;
```

---

2019-Oct-08
Just stumbled on an issue with `app.manifest`:
`compatibility` section with `supportedOS` elements was stripped out during deployment.

Same root cause;  the line reading it should set `preserveStream` to **true**:

```
ApplicationManifest am = ManifestReader.ReadManifest( "ApplicationManifest", sPathMft, true ) as ApplicationManifest;
```

Answer (score 1):

I also needed to add CompatibleFrameworks. I also tried do add the CompatibleFrameworks like this (which does not work)

```
dm.CompatibleFrameworks.Add(...);
```

My solution was to set:

```
dm.TargetFrameworkMoniker = ".NETFramework,Version=v4.0";
```

After this the Manifest generation was correct.

Be careful If you set the TargetFrameworkMoniker before WriteManifest you have the <compatibleFrameworks> twice and your application file is corrupt. Here is my solution for this:

```
DeployManifest dm = ManifestReader.ReadManifest("DeployManifest", applicationFileName, false) as DeployManifest;
dm.ResolveFiles();
//doing stuff..
dm.UpdateFileInfo();
ManifestWriter.WriteManifest(dm, applicationFileName);
dm.TargetFrameworkMoniker = ".NETFramework,Version=v4.0";
ManifestWriter.WriteManifest(dm, applicationFileName);
```